# Duplicate class как исправить?

Tags: android, github, gradle

Я новичок. В своем проекте я использую библиотеку с `github`, но ёё `SDK` не сходился с моим. Покопавшись в инете я решил форкнуть её. Форкнул. Залил на `jitpack`. Изменил `gradle`. Но при компиляции получаю ошибку. Так же `IDE` не видит мою библиотеку и `import` остаётся на прошлую библиотеку.

[Оригинальная библиотека(тык)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view), [форкнутая(тык).](https://github.com/stas57RUS/expandable-recycler-view)

**Не работает import:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ошибка:**

```
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandCollapseController found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.MultiTypeExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners.ExpandCollapseListener found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners.GroupExpandCollapseListener found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.listeners.OnGroupClickListener found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.models.ExpandableGroup found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.models.ExpandableGroup$1 found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.models.ExpandableList found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.models.ExpandableListPosition found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.viewholders.ChildViewHolder found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
Duplicate class com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.viewholders.GroupViewHolder found in modules jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.4-runtime.jar (com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4) and jetified-expandablerecyclerview-1.6-runtime.jar (com.github.stas57RUS.expandable-recycler-view:expandablerecyclerview:1.6)
```

**gradle(Modul):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.arraylist"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.stas57RUS:expandable-recycler-view:1.6'

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
```

**gradle(Project):**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Удаляем ненужный

Comment: Так я удалил старую библиотеку из gradle

Comment: Clean или Rebuild делали?

Comment: сделал, не помогло

Comment: А вы смотрели свой форк? там и близко нет пакета `com.github.STAS57` :)

Comment: А каким образом его добавить?:)  `IDE` всё равно предлагает мне старую библиотеку, скриншот - https://skr.sh/s3cTPhW2FRm?a

Comment: Пакеты классов в оригинальной и форкнутой либе полностью идентичны. Положено вообще то классы форка помещать в другом пакете, типа: `com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.fork` или же почистить локальный кэш грейдла, чтобы оттуда удалить оригинальные либы `com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview`

Comment: можете более подробно объяснить как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в форке все пакеты com.thoughtbot а не com.github.STAS57, так что импорты и должны быть как у изначальной либы.

Но главное то что в build.gradle модуля expandablecheckrecyclerview присутствует зависимость `implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.4'`
Замените её на implementation project(':expandablerecyclerview')

Comment: увы, не помогло